# symmetric encryption in c# resembles JAVA

Tags: java, c#, .net, encryption, encryption-symmetric

```
private static byte[] encryptData(ByteArrayOutputStream data, byte[] symmetricKey) throws EncryptionException {
        try {
            SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(symmetricKey, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(data.toByteArray());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException |
                InvalidKeyException |
                BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new EncryptionException(e);
        }
    }
```

I have a situation where I need to encrypt data using .NET and decrypt the same data using JAVA. Essentially, I need to rewrite the above encryption method in .NET.

```
public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] plainText)
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, magicIV))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cs.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                        }
                        byte[] cipherText = ms.ToArray();
                        return cipherText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code I used somewhere mandates IV which JAVA is not asking for. What is the IV used in JAVA code?

I tried many links which didn't work.
[Symmetric Encryption between .NET and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872771/symmetric-encryption-between-net-and-java)

Please help

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Such questions as yours should be closed as *too broad*.

Comment: You should probably ditch the above code altogether.  It is far from secure.

Answer (score 2):

If your current Java decryption code also does not ask for an IV (and your decryption returns the same data you encrypted) then `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` is returning an object using the ECB block mode.

.NET symmetric algorithms default to the CBC block mode, which requires an IV.

You have a couple of options:

- Set `aesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB` before calling `CreateEncryptor`.

  - You probably don't want this, see the penguin at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Common_modes.
- Pass `aesProvider.IV` to the IV parameter of `CreateEncryptor`.  The IV property will make a cryptographically random value on the first read if it's not set.

  - You will need to pass this data to the decryption routine, which should then use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", and set the IV however one does that in Java.
  - One common method of transport is to simply prepend the data to the ciphertext, then just pick off the first 16 bytes at decryption time.
  - DO NOT use a fixed value for an IV, because it's then almost the same as ECB.